# cada vez que le doy correr en eclipse, no me aparece nada en la consola, ayuda

Tags: java

```
package tarea;

public class Trabajador {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private long documento;
private String nombre;
double valorHora;
int horasTrabajo; 
long salarioTotal;

void salaraioTotal (){

double salarioTotal = valorHora*horasTrabajo;
System.out.println("salario total" + salarioTotal);

 if(valorHora >= 80){
      System.out.println("salarioTotal"+ 100000);

if(salarioTotal <= 1500000) {
    System.out.println("Deduccion salud"+ (salarioTotal*100)/5 + "rte fuente" + (salarioTotal*100)/0);      

  }else {

 if(salarioTotal >= 1500001 && salarioTotal <= 3000000) {
     System.out.println("deduccion salud" + (salarioTotal*100)/8 + "rte fuente" + (salarioTotal*100)/3);
 }else{

  if(salarioTotal <= 3000000) {
      System.out.println("deduccion salud" + (salarioTotal*100)/12 + "rte fuente" + (salarioTotal*100)/5);


  }


 }

  }


 }
}

  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No tienes nada en el *main*... Evidentemente no se mostrara nada en consola. Tu código debería ir en el método *main* o debería llamar a algun otro método que contenga tu código. 
Otro consejo es que no uses tantos if y uses la sentencia switch, ademas veo que no inicias tus variables e intentas dividir por cero, cosas que te van a dar mas problemas.

Te dejo este ejemplo que funciona, debes cambiar el 0 por otro valor, yo por ejemplo le puse 10.

```
public class example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long documento = 12345678;
        String nombre = "Lucas";
        double valorHora = 5.00;
        int horasTrabajo = 8;
        long salarioTotal = 2000;

        if (valorHora >= 80) {
            System.out.println("salarioTotal" + 100000);
        }

        if (salarioTotal <= 1500000) {
            // NO PUEDES DIVIDIR POR CERO ! 
            System.out.println("Deduccion salud" + (salarioTotal * 100) / 5 + "rte fuente" + (salarioTotal * 100) / 10);
        } else {
            if (salarioTotal >= 1500001 && salarioTotal <= 3000000) {
                System.out.println(
                        "deduccion salud" + (salarioTotal * 100) / 8 + "rte fuente" + (salarioTotal * 100) / 3);
            } else {
                if (salarioTotal <= 3000000) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "deduccion salud" + (salarioTotal * 100) / 12 + "rte fuente" + (salarioTotal * 100) / 5);
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

De este modo por consola me imprime ***Deduccion salud40000rte fuente20000***

Comment: hola, todavia no me devuelve nada en la consola, y si agrego:             
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    salarioTotal();
}                                                                                                                             me que salario total no esta definido en Trabajador

Comment: @santiagolondoñovelez He modificado mi respuesta, noté que en uno de los if estas dividiendo por 0, eso dará una excepción.

Comment: muchas gracias, ya funciona

Comment: Genial! No te olvides darle el "tick" a mi respuesta para marcarla como correcta y asi ayudar a los que tengan el mismo problema en un futuro :). Un placer @santiagolondoñovelez.

Answer (score 2):

Ya se que te funcionó, pero puedes tomarlo como un consejo, en vez de escribir el método dentro del main, podrías simplemente haberlo llamado desde este; por ejemplo:

```
public class Trabajador{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      salarioTotal();
   }

   void salarioTotal(){
   ...
   }
}
```

Y finalmente para que luego no te enredes intentando releer el código, puedes facilitarte la vida usando un switch(...) o en vez de hacer if(){...}else{if(){...}}, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera if(){...}else if(){...}